# How should one approach the signing of ERC20 token transactions with an offline device?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, wallets, offline, dai

I use an offline PC as a cold wallet. It works in combination with 2 USB drives: the 1st has Tails OS; the 2nd has my key files, a copy of MyCrypto desktop, and my encrypted account info. I can sign an offline transaction for later broadcasting on a separate connected PC using this set-up. Problem is, I can only do ETH transactions. I'd like to perform similar transactions with ERC20s (specifically, Dai) with this type of solution, but without having to buy a hardware wallet or smartphone.

For example, suppose I transfer some ETH from my cold wallet to a hot wallet, use the hot wallet to purchase some Dai off a DEX, and then finally deposit this Dai back into my cold wallet. What is the best approach to then transfer the Dai from the cold wallet back into a hot wallet using my set-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MyCrypto to sign ERC-20 token transactions offline as well. On the send screen, click on the dropdown next to the amount field to choose what token to send. All tokens on the default token list (including DAI) will be visible. If the thoken you want to send is not on there yet, you can add a custom token too, with the "Add custom token" button on the right.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't notice this option. I'm using a very old version of MyCrypto. I'll have to get myself updated and pay closer attention. Thanks for the clarification.